# What adhesive do I need for this fireplace cladding?

Tags: fireplace, adhesive, thinset

I have a fireplace where the stones are falling out and some are loose. This is my first time dealing with fireplaces so i’m not sure what type of stone this is. What type of adhesive would I need for this? Heat resistant? Can I do this myself or would I have to contract someone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like wood behind it, so I doubt you need heat resistant.  One of the construction adhesives should work.  Clean the cladding and the base well.

Comment: Any construction adhesive? So I need thinset mortar or is that too heavy for something like this?

Comment: I was thinking more of the adhesives that come in tubes.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say this installation suffers from a significant lack of adhesive. I'd agree with @crip659 that some construction adhesive sounds like an _answer_...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally try to find a similar product (or the specific product if you can somehow identify it) and look at its detailed installation instructions, because what you have there looks like *doing it wrong* from here.

Fire/heat resistance seems like it should not matter in this area, as there's plywood backing. For that, look to the documentation of the actual fireplace this is surrounding, if you can sort out what it is - many modern units are "zero clearance" but some are not, so heat tolerance might matter for parts of the surround.

To me, the whole surround looks sloppily done with no mortar or equivalent between the brick-like stones, so I'd be inclined to rip it down and start over from scratch, but if you just want to do a quick and dirty repair, gluing things in with a polyurethane construction adhesive (glue in a caulking tube) might work until the rest of this bad job falls down.